# Disk Utility can't resize container although there is free space

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I have MacBook Pro 16" with 1TB. It had macOS Catalina installed. When macOS Big Sur came out, I created a new partition and installed macOS Big Sur on it. Then I wanted my 778 GB back and tried to delete Macintosh HD partition (it had Catalina installed). I erased it, but I couldn't delete it. Finally, I deleted it using `diskutil apfs deleteContainer`. Now I have only macOS Big Sur partition but it only uses 222GB altough my MacBook has 778 GB left. `diskutil apfs list` shows that there is only one container.

```
 +-- Container disk1 DFC90CF5-A6CC-4E13-AF98-3B90ED5788B5
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      222528602112 B (222.5 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   185862705152 B (185.9 GB) (83.5% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       36665896960 B (36.7 GB) (16.5% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 438FC4AC-5F27-4362-B253-71B36B93180F
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       222528602112 B (222.5 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 2EF8C8CF-A45C-4B22-8758-CB9051BD055F
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD – dane (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
    |   Capacity Consumed:         169389010944 B (169.4 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 Yes (Unlocked)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 EA4F7F96-351D-4A94-9E35-50F31C28EE15
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Preboot
    |   Capacity Consumed:         282976256 B (283.0 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 831782DC-51D8-4B04-B813-AB48C29A6705
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         661774336 B (661.8 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 C1E9108B-20DE-4573-831C-C810F2BF64CB
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
    |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/VM
    |   Capacity Consumed:         24576 B (24.6 KB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s5 A4131650-8CF9-42C2-BE28-82301B62B104
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s5 (System)
        Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               Not Mounted
        Capacity Consumed:         15392522240 B (15.4 GB)
        Sealed:                    Broken
        FileVault:                 Yes (Unlocked)
        Encrypted:                 No
        |
        Snapshot:                  20283AAA-31E2-4041-BE5E-786DAB66AEBA
        Snapshot Disk:             disk1s5s1
        Snapshot Mount Point:      /
        Snapshot Sealed:           Yes
```

Below is the output of `diskutil list disk0`.

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
                    (free space)                         777.7 GB   -
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         222.5 GB   disk0s2
```

I know that erasing the disk will fix this, but I want to know if there is another way to fix it without doing this.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of the question [How to make remove free space and make APFS container take it up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406962/how-to-make-remove-free-space-and-make-apfs-container-take-it-up). Although, without the output from the command `diskutil list disk0`, I can not confirm this.

Comment: This is the output of diskutil list disk0.                                                                                #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
                    (free space)                         777.7 GB   -
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         222.5 GB   disk0s2

Comment: You have the same question as I have linked to. You can not expand a container upward. The best you can do is replicate (clone) to a new container. I would backup my important data before attempting this.

Comment: Can merging both partitions help?

Comment: If you use the `diskutil` command to merge partitions, then the contents of `disk0s2` would be lost.

Comment: I managed to create a new 777 GB partition and I thought that I could merge both partitions but use disk0s2 as source so it is not erased. If it is impossible, then I will need to copy data to a new partition and install macOS on it like the question mentioned by you says.

Comment: You have a nice idea, however your idea is not possible by using macOS. The instructions are very specific. The partitions must be sequential and the contents are only preserved for the first partition. Look at the current output from `diskutil list disk0`. The partition you want preserve is the last partition.