# Monterey retake space from free space partition

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition, spaces

I have tried the method from [this page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406962/how-to-make-remove-free-space-and-make-apfs-container-take-it-up/407055#407055) but I cannot manage to reclaim the free space.

Output of diskutil list:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
                    (free space)                         799.0 GB   -
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         201.2 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +201.2 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     104.3 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.2 GB    disk1s2
   3:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.2 GB    disk1s2s1
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 1.2 GB     disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      20.5 KB    disk1s5
```

And then I tired code `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1 0`

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1 0
Started APFS operation
Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required in your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of partition map usable space
zhuhaoran@zhuhaorandeMacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk2 0
Could not find disk for disk2
zhuhaoran@zhuhaorandeMacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1 0
Started APFS operation
Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required in your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of partition map usable space
zhuhaoran@zhuhaorandeMacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
Could not find disk for disk0s2
```

Now there is 799 GB of free space in my Macbook and I cannot use it.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Terminal output is best posted as 'code' [ctrl k] rather than images. Images are an unsearchable resource & cannot be read by sight-impaired reader software.

Comment: I have changed images to code, please do help me check it.

Comment: Better, thanks. I reformatted as code, you'd formatted as a quote. Ctrl/K vs Ctrl/Q

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you question appears to show you are entering commands without understanding in the hope something desirable will happen. This a dangerous approach which could lead to the loss of important data. The answer below is less dependent on commands than the answer you have [linked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406962/how-to-make-remove-free-space-and-make-apfs-container-take-it-up/407055#407055) to. Hopefully, this increase the change of success.

1. Open a Terminal application window and enter the command below.

   ```
   diskutil addpartition disk0s1 apfs NewMacHD 0
   ```
2. Download Monterey from the App Store.
3. Install Monterey to volume `NewMacHD`. After you are convinced Monterey is installed to the `NewMacHD` volume, move the Install macOS Monterey application to the Trash.
4. Boot to Monterey on the `NewMacHD` volume.
5. Use the Migration Assistant to transfer from the `Macintosh HD` volume to the `NewMacHD` volume.
6. After you convinced all useful data has been migrated, use the Disk Utility to delete the partition containing the `Macintosh HD` volume.

   > Note: After using the Disk Utility to perform an operation, you should quit and then open the Disk Utility to see the results.
7. Use the Disk Utility to rename the `NewMacHD` volume to `Macintosh HD`.

Comment: Thank you so so so so much!!! It works.

Comment: If you feel my post answered your question, then you should accept my answer. This will place a green check mark next to my answer. This will also inform others an answer was found.